# mongoexport fails to parse query

Tags: mongodb

```
$ mongoexport -h mongo1.pilot.com:27017 -d tracking -c TRACKING_DATA -u API -p ******** -o TRACKING_DATA-bk.json -q '{datecreated:{$lt:ISODate("2015-02-01T00:00:00.00Z")}}'
    connected to: mongo1.pilot.com:27017
```

This is the error I get:

```
assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Bad characters in value: offset:18 of:{datecreated:{$lt:ISODate("2015-02-01T00:00:00.00Z")}}
```

however I can query the collection directly using the same query and get the results:

```
 db.TRACKING_DATA.find({datecreated:{$lt:ISODate("2015-02-01T00:00:00.00Z")}}).count()
19580342
```

Does mongoexport use a different parser?

Comment: Which version of mongodb?

Comment: 2.6 I believe, are there different parsers for different versions of mongo?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in Jira for MongoDB, the ability to parse ISODate in query by `mongoexport` was not added until 3.0 https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-530.

Comment: why wouldn't it? it's shell syntax, shell is js interpreter.  mongoexport is a utility that doesn't know how to deal with "ISODate()" in older versions, anyway.